# How to avoid memcpy if number of blocks depends on device variable?

Tags: cuda

I am computing a number, X, on the device. Now I need to launch a kernel with X threads. I can set the blockSize to 1024. Is there a way to set the number of blocks to ceil(X / 1024) without performing a memcpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. Use dynamic parallelism (if feasible). Rather than copying the result back to determine the execution parameters of the next launch, just have the device perform the next launch itself.
2. Use zero-copy or managed memory. In that case the GPU writes directly to CPU memory over the PCI-e bus, rather than requiring an explicit memory transfer.

Of those options, dynamic parallelism and managed memory require hardware features which are not available on all GPUs. Zero-copy memory is supported by all GPUs with compute capability >= 1.1, which in practice is just about every CUDA compatible device ever made.

Comment: I honestly don't see how answer relates to question. Can you elaborate the link between the two?

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET: I am sorry if you don't understand the question. The (simple) question is: if one kernel calculates a result, and the size of the grid for the next kernel is determined by the value of that result, is it possible to avoid having to do an explicit memory transfer of that value back to the device before the next kernel launch is performed.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating.

Answer (score 1):

An example of using managed memory, as outlined by @talonmies, allowing kernel1 to determine the number of blocks for kernel2 without an explicit `memcpy`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

using namespace std;

__device__ __managed__ int kernel2_blocks;

__global__ void kernel1() {
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        kernel2_blocks = 42;
    }
}

__global__ void kernel2() {
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        printf("block: %d\n", blockIdx.x);
    }
}

int main() {
    kernel1<<<1, 1024>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    kernel2<<<kernel2_blocks, 1024>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```